# Нужно сохранить число c TextField (JavaFX) в переменную (double)

Tags: java, javafx, ui, text, jtextfield

Есть TextField и есть переменная, как счидать даные с TextField?
Какой handler использовать или это делаться? Нигде не могу найти пример .
В какую функию нужно вставлть handler .
Знаю что нужно

```
double i = Double.perseDouble(text.getText());
```

Но где и как , с  этим траблы. Буду очень благодарный

Хочу что бы Height, Weight задавал пользователь
Код

Controller.java

```
package sample;




import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class Controller implements ActionListener{
    private static Color colorOfFigure;
    private static int colorIndex, figureIndex;
    private static double HEIGHT = 30;
    private static int WEIGHT = 50;


    @FXML
    public static TextField height;
    @FXML
    private static TextField weight;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> colorMenue;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> figureMenue;
    @FXML
    private Canvas myCanvas;
    GraphicsContext gc;
    @FXML
    Button go;


    @FXML
    public void printFigure() {
        //COLOR MENUE
        colorMenue.setOnAction(event -> {
            colorIndex =
                    colorMenue.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        });

        //FIGURES MENUE
        figureMenue.setOnAction(event -> {
            figureIndex = figureMenue.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        });
        printFigure(figureIndex);

        }





    public Color switchColor(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                colorOfFigure = Color.YELLOW;
                break;
            case 1:
                colorOfFigure = Color.GREEN;
                break;
            case 2:
                colorOfFigure = Color.BLACK;
                break;
            case 3:
                colorOfFigure = Color.RED;
                break;
            case 4:
                colorOfFigure = Color.BLUE;
                break;
        }
        return colorOfFigure;

    }

    void printFigure(int figureIndex) {
        gc = myCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(switchColor(colorIndex));
        gc.setStroke(switchColor(colorIndex));
        switch (figureIndex) {
            case 0:
                gc.strokeLine(0, 0, 187, 160);
                break;
            case 1:
                gc.fillRoundRect(110, 60, 30, 30, 10, 10);
                break;
            case 2:
                gc.fillRect(187, 160, 100, 100);
                break;
            case 3:
                gc.fillPolygon(new double[]{10, 30, 10},
                        new double[]{210, 210, 240, 240,}, 4);
            case 4:
                gc.fillOval(187, 160, 100, 100);
                break;

        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void cleanCanvas() {
        gc.setFill(Color.LAVENDER);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, myCanvas.getWidth(), myCanvas.getHeight());
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        height.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
                    System.out.println(height.getText());
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage stage;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        this.stage = stage;
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("printFiguresUI.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("Print Figure | by marchenko BIT1-15");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 400));
        stage.show();
        }







    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

printFigureUI.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="26.0" layoutY="306.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#printFigure" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="158.0" text="print" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="figureMenue" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="52.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="            none">
      <items>
         <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Apple" />
            <String fx:value="Orange" />
            <String fx:value="Pear" />
            <String fx:value="Triq" />
         </FXCollections>
      </items>
      </ComboBox>
      <Label layoutX="34.0" layoutY="26.0" text="Choose the figure" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="colorMenue" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="135.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="            none">
      <items>
         <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Yellow" />
            <String fx:value="Green" />
            <String fx:value="Black" />
            <String fx:value="Red" />
            <String fx:value="Blue" />
         </FXCollections>
      </items>
   </ComboBox>
      <Label layoutX="34.0" layoutY="111.0" text="Choose the color" />
      <Canvas fx:id="myCanvas" height="400.0" layoutX="209.0" layoutY="2.0" width="499.0" />

      <Separator layoutX="206.0" layoutY="-11.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="365.0" prefWidth="6.0" />
      <Label layoutX="71.0" layoutY="164.0" text="figure's size" />
      <Button layoutX="26.0" layoutY="341.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cleanCanvas" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="158.0" text="clean" textFill="#f20000" />
      <TextField layoutX="32.0" layoutY="188.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="69.0" text="HEIGHT" />
      <TextField layoutX="115.0" layoutY="188.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="69.0" text="WEIGHT" />
      <TextField alignment="CENTER" layoutX="30.0" layoutY="257.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="69.0" text="X" />
      <TextField alignment="CENTER" layoutX="118.0" layoutY="256.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="69.0" text="Y" />
      <Label layoutX="50.0" layoutY="235.0" text="figure's position" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Раза 3 перечетал в чем пробела то?

Comment: я хочу что бы с Textfield исчитовальсь даные. Но не выходит это реализовать.

Comment: У тебя ошибка брат, `double i = Double.perseDouble(text.getText());` НАДО ТАК `double i = Double.parseDouble(text.getText());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно завести проперти подходящего типа, в котором будет сохранятся нужное значение, а чтобы не путаться текстовое поле лучше переименовать в heigthField:

```
private final DoubleProperty heigth = new SimpleDoubleProperty(30d);

@FXML
public TextField heigthField;
```

Далее в методе initialize контроллера привяжем значение текстового поля к проперти, NumberStringConverter обеспечит автоматическую конвертацию:

```
heigthField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(heigth, new NumberStringConverter());
```

Теперь значение можно получать из heigth:

```
heigth.get()
```

Можно на него повесить слушатель и делать что-либо когда значение изменяется:

```
heigth.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {System.out.println(newValue);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так.

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{

   //DI dly polu4enia textfield-ov
   @FXML public TextField height;

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
      height.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
                System.out.println(height.getText());
            }

        }
    });
   }
```

а в FXML установи ИД для textfields:

```
<TextArea fx:id="height" .../>
```